# Handling Animation of a Textblock that repeats forever in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, animation, windows-phone-8

I have a textblock in my app, and I want to make a simple animation with it. I want just that it moves to left, until apparently "leaving the device", and returning on the other side, back to its place... as if circling the device horizontally... repeating this forever!

I tried doing like this:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="txbAnimated" FontFamily="Segoe WP SemiBold"
    FontSize="17" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0"
    TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="My Text" VerticalAlignment="Center"
    TextAlignment="Center">
    <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
        <CompositeTransform TranslateX="-550" />
    </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
</TextBlock>

<TextBlock x:Name="txbAnimated2" Margin="550,0,-550,0" FontFamily="Segoe WP
    SemiBold" FontSize="17" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="My Text" VerticalAlignment="Center"
    TextAlignment="Center">
    <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
        <CompositeTransform TranslateX="-550" />
    </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
</TextBlock>

<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Name="movement">
                <DoubleAnimation
                Storyboard.TargetName="txbAnimated"
                Duration="0:0:2"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty=" (UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)"
                From="0" To="-550"
                BeginTime="0:0:10"
                RepeatBehavior="1x"/>
            </Storyboard>

            <Storyboard x:Name="movement2">
                <DoubleAnimation
                Storyboard.TargetName="txbAnimated2"
                Duration="0:0:2"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty=" (UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)"
                From="0" To="-550"
                BeginTime="0:0:10"
                RepeatBehavior="1x"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

And on Main:

```
    private void StartBanner()
    {
        movement.Begin();
        movement.Completed += movement_Completed;

        movement2.Begin();
        movement2.Completed += movement2_Completed;
    }

    private void movement_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        movement.Begin();
        movement.Completed += movement2_Completed;
    }

    private void movement2_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        movement2.Begin();
        movement2.Completed += movement_Completed;
    }
```

I didn't use "RepeatBehavior = forever" because I want that the animation stops after one cycle, wait a few seconds, then repeat it.

It worked this way, but it is interfering on others elements behaviors on UI...
So, I read this article [Make animations smooth (XAML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh994638.aspx), but I'm working with Windows Phone 8, and not all tips there works for WP8...

Does anyone know the best way of make this animation, without mess with another elements on UI?

Comment: Have you tried setting Duration for Storyboard?

Comment: I did it: "Duration="0:0:2""

Comment: But you set Duration for DoubleAnimation. You can also set different longer Duration for Storyboard.

Comment: Well, I fixed it! The key was that I didn't know the storyboard could have a duration or repeatBehavior... I combined the RepeatBehavior on Storyboard with Duration of DoubleAnimation, and I got the animation I wanted, without using the completed events (that I believe it was causing my problem).. Very thanks!!